# MySQL Query Fetch Time increases when LEFT JOIN with big table

Tags: mysql, query-performance, innodb, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I am fetching the same amount of data with 2 different queries. However, one of them have a fetching time of ~x130 compared to the other. Being the only difference between the two queries a `LEFT JOIN` with a big table (4M rows).

Especifically, my problem goes like this:
I have `table_a` with 200K rows. `table_b` with 100 rows and `table_c` with 4M rows. The fields involved are indexed. `table_a` and `table_c` have a `one to many` cardinality.

My query looks something like this:

```sql
       SELECT
          a.id
       FROM
          table_a a
          LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.b_id
          LEFT JOIN table_c c ON c.id = b.c_id
       GROUP BY a.id;
```

MySQL Workbench tells me that this query takes ~4s of Duration and 130 seconds of Fetch Time.
However, when I remove the second LEFT JOIN with the big table, the query takes <1s of Duration and <1s Fetch Time.

I clearly understand why the query **duration** is increased. I am doing a kinda heavy left join. But, my question is: Why the **fetching time** is so much higher, if the fetched data is the same?

I have already increased `innodb_buffer_pool_size` with no success.

I am working in **MySQL 8.0.19**, with innodb as tables engine.

Is there something I am missing here?
Thanks in advance for the help!

**EDIT 1:**
Removing the `GROUP BY` also improves the performance <1s of Duration and ~1s Fetch Time

**EDIT 2:**
The query needs the `GROUP BY` and `LEFT JOINS` for a latter `WHERE` and `HAVING`. I decided to omit them for simplicity of the question and due to them not being relevant in terms of the initial problem (high fetching time). After using EXPLAIN ANALYZE, it seems that this high Fetching Time is a weird bug of Workbench and in reality the Duration of the query is the problem.

Comment: Show DDL for all 3 tables, including indices and FKs (columns not used in them and/or the query may be skipped).

Comment: It dutifully evaluated the useless LEFT JOINs, figuring that "the user asked for it".

Answer (score 2):

> My query looks something like this:
>
> ```
>   SELECT
>      a.id
>   FROM
>      table_a a
>      LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.b_id
>      LEFT JOIN table_c c ON c.id = b.c_id
>   GROUP BY a.id;
> ```

Your query is an equvalent of

```
SELECT [DISTINCT] a.id
FROM table_a a
```

---

PS. Show real DDL and queries texts - your ability to create adequate models is insufficient.